# Swift assign a float variable

Tags: ios, swift

I found a issue that seems strange, or something I don't understand.  The following is a very simple variable assignment:

```
let f: Float = 310.15
```

In debugger, I see it is 310.149994
I need to send the value as 310.15 to server, but 310.149994 is received instead.

Is this a Swift compiler or runtime bug?  Or any way I can ensure 310.15 float is sent?  (I cannot change the server API signature)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken?r=SearchResults&s=1|817.0710

Comment: Use `Decimal` instead of Float or Double if you need to avoid rounding errors.

Comment: When you convert .1 or 1/10 to base 2 (binary) you get a repeating pattern after the decimal point, just like trying to represent 1/3 in base 10. The value is not exact, and therefore you can't do exact math with it using normal floating point methods. original answer in - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken

Comment: Thanks for all the comments above answer the question I have.  It is @Gereon's suggestion solve my immediate issue, and I finally realize why most of the modem programming language provide Decimal class in additional to those primitive data types.  Thanks all.

Answer (score -3):

**Try this one**

```
let f : Float = 310.149954

print(round(1000*f)/1000)
```

> result : 310.15